# Remove classes at page load Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove a known class using `JQUERY`, however, I've a scenario, that if the current page loads, it checks by the class that if radio button/checkboxes are checked, remove that class. I'm checking the checkboxes by their particular id. How I can set this scenario that to find the checked boxes and remove that particular class at page load.

My Code:

```
if ($("#idd").is(":checked")) // check box or radio button
    $('#divID').removeClass('removeThisClass'); // div id to remove that class
```

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: you want to know how to use events on checkboxes/radio button?

Comment: $('#checkbox1').change(function() {
     
    });

Comment: @JoshuaByer this function will just call when the mouse over and change that thing. I want to do this on page load automatically.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<select id="idd">
    <option  val="whichdiv">Test</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        var divtodelete= $(this).val();
        $('#' + divtodelete).removeClass('removeThisClass'); 
    });
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function () {
        var divtodelete= $(this).val();
        $('#' + divtodelete).removeClass('removeThisClass'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to perform this on every checkbox & radio button on page load.

Comment: I answered my question, thanks for the response. I'm voting your response.

Comment: nops nops .. I'vent used that. Why should I do this

Answer (score 0):

I did that using `.each` so that when ever I reloads the page, and the checkboxes that are checked by default, it automatically removes their classes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {
$($(this)).removeClass('classToRemove');
});

$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
$($(this)).removeClass('x-hidden');
});
});
```